# How to set Pixel Perfect Camera size to 5?

Tags: unity-game-engine

2D game. Orthographic camera.
I need the camera size to be 5 units (as is the default.)
With a regular camera, everything is simple - you set it to any size.

How to set the size to 5 Pixel Perfect Camera? Pixel Perfect Camera is a standard out-of-the-box script in Unity.
Here are my camera settings.

[Camera settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3pYA.jpg)

You see, Size=5. But that's not true (the actual size is shown by the green frame, not the frame of a regular camera).

The resolution at which I develop the game is 1920x1080. Pixels per unit 100 (default).
In total, Pixel Perfect Camera calculates the camera height (1080/100)/2=5.4 units. We launch the game and see the camera size is 5.4.

[Camera settings when i launched the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYfyZ.jpg)

Pixel Perfect Camera changes the camera height from 5 to 5.4.
And I need 5. I need to control the player's field of view.
**How to set Pixel Perfect Camera size to 5?**

Comment: You can't have both. If PP component allows you to change it to 5 it will no longer be pixel perfect. You probably should read how camera fov, screen resolution and sprites' pixels per unit relate to achieve PP. To have PP their ratio must always be a whole number. To make fov 5 then you must  change pixels per unit setting on your camera PP component and on all your sprites. That's unavoidable price if you want PP.

Comment: Out of curiosity have you tried this in the built .exe game, or just in play mode in the editor? Since the editor play mode is not full screen I wonder if that has an effect?